# Monitor IIS web application using Azure application insights

Tags: azure, iis, web-applications, azure-application-insights

I've an on-prem IIS web app that I want to monitor using Azure Application Insights, but I cannot find an agent to install on the Web server. Any recommendations?

Comment: Ths is a valid question.  Just edit out "Any recommendations" and replace it with "Is there an on-prem App Insights agent available?"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now#monitor-a-live-iis-web-app Please refer to this document to get details on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you find is a local agent which will be installed on your IIS servers called Application Insights Status Monitor. You can install it using Microsoft Web Platform Installer or get an install link from this blog.

[Using Azure Application Insights with On-Premises Servers](https://unhandled.wordpress.com/2018/02/01/using-azure-application-insights-with-on-premises-servers/)

Comment: I'm trying to enable the live metrics by running the following cmdlet, but it does not work:
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Version 2.7.1
May I know why?
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Version 2.7.1

Comment: LiveMetric is part of https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector/ which you can get either directly or by installing the Web package which indirectly install the PerfCounterCollector https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web/2.7.1

Comment: When I download it, i get a .nupkg file, how can I install it?